# BURG Bootloader

Tags: upgrade, partitioning, burg

I have just installed 11.10 on top of an existing Win7 Install, and I would like to try BURG, however I am curious as to how BURG handles distro upgrades. Will Burg break when 12.04 comes out? and is there any danger to my windows partition?

Comment: Upgrades can be problematic as you know. When the time comes, read the release notes ;) See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/86942/update-all-packages-of-11-04-then-upgrade-to-11-10-or-upgrade-to-11-10-without/86956#86956

Answer (score 1):

There is no danger to your windows partition, but BURG will be replaced by GRUB if you upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04. It also did not do too well with normal upgrades for me (I'm referring to something as simple as apply updates to the system).

To be honest, most of what BURG can do, GRUB can do now if configured correctly, so I would not advise going with BURG.